I'm writing Pine Script in Trading View but I keep getting this error
//Erroneous Script
[diPlus, diMinus, adx] = ta.dmi(close, 14)     //14-period length
This string was to replace a previous error where "ta.adx", is no longer in use in v6. Function is to reference Average Directional Index indicator, which is supposedly "built-in", but can't be found.
//Error
Cannot call 'ta.dmi' with argument 'diLength'='close'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.
The previous script apparently didn't have the correct use of ta.dmi() with price series and length.

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong and what's needed to fix it. Did you read it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The first argument of the ta.dmi() is length which expects a simple int. You are using close which is series float for this parameter. That is what the error message is telling you.
You should be passing two simple ints.
For example:
[diplus, diminus, adx] = ta.dmi(14, 21)

